# hide control while resizing window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, window-resize

I'm trying to hide a control during a window resize because it's not behaving right otherwise. However in WPF there doesn't seem to be any `OnBeginResize`-ish event.
Any suggestions how to achieve this in WPF?

Comment: there is the WM_RESIZE event

Comment: Why dont you try do make it behave right?^^

Comment: @FlorianGl I got it behaving correctly now, it was becoming crazy by having multiple anchors defined (Top, Left, Right, Bottom) all at once >u<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind a property(Notifiable) to your window width so when the width changes Setter of this property will be invoked and within this setter you can have the logic to hide your control.

```
<Window x:Class="SiemensEnergy.Frw.Main.Client.UI.Views.MainWindowView"        
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:SiemensEnergy.Frw.Main.Client.UI.ViewModels" 
        Title="MainWindow" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        Width="{Binding WindowWidthProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
</Window>
```

Comment: Wait!, shouldn't I bind ActualWidth and ActualHeight instead?

Comment: You should set a default value for this width property (return some value from property getter), That will be the width of the window when it loads first time. later while you change the window width, setter will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Window_SizeChanged?

```
<Window x:Class="TestControls.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:m="clr-namespace:WFControls;assembly=WFControls"
        xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:WFControls.Fernfracht;assembly=WFControls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">
    <DockPanel>

  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks, however this seems to be called after the re-size stuff has happened. It'd be optimum to know when to hide and when to show my misbehaving control.